# Phonegap android build error on macosx

Tags: android, cordova, terminal, phonegap-build

I'm trying to build an apk from my phonegap project. When I run `phonegap build android` I get `Error: EPERM, operation not permitted` error so I tried `sudo phonegap build android` but I get this error:

```
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
```

When I run `sudo android` I get the android manager so I have correctly exported android path. What is the problem then?

This is part of my .profile file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Iman/Documents/SDKs/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

For OSX:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Reference the Installation guide here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/

Comment: I think my export and yours are identical but I still get that error when I use ```phonegap build android``` with sudo.